# Symbolic PDE manipulation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, expression-manipulation

I'd like to transform a PDE in a way such that I can express a temporal derivative as a spatial derivative using some known relation.

Very simple example:

```
Assuming[{D[h[x, t], t] - D[h[x, t], x] == 0}, 
 Solve[Integrate[D[h[x, t], t], x] + a[x, t] == 0, a[x, t]]]
```

This gives me as expected a nice answer: `{{a[x, t] -> -h[x, t]}}`.

However, if I change the assumtion slightly this does not work any longer:

```
Assuming[{D[h[x, t], t] + D[h[x, t], x] == 0}, 
 Solve[Integrate[D[h[x, t], t], x] + a[x, t] == 0, a[x, t]]]
```

yields `{{a[x,t]->-\[Integral](h^(0,1))[x,t]\[DifferentialD]x}}`.

I have tried any kind of reformulation of the assumption which did not help. This is just a small example, my real assumptions are even more complicated.
Any ideas?

Comment: `Solve[{D[h[x,t],t]+D[h[x,t],x]==0,Integrate[D[h[x,t],t],x]+a[x,t]==0},{a[x,t],D[h[x,t],t]}]` works but I am not sure how helpful.robust this is fore more complicated equations/expressions.

Comment: It even works for my complicated problem:
This answer gave me a better understanding of the solve command. Thank you very much!

Comment: Here is how it looks for my complicated expressions:

`consLaw1 = D[h[x, t], t] + D[m[x, t], x] == 0;`

`consLaw2 = 
  D[m[x, t], t] + D[m[x, t]^2/h[x, t] + g/2 h[x, t]^2, x] + 
    g h[x, t] D[hb[x], x] == 0;`

`Etotal[h, m] = 
  1/2 m[x, t]^2 /h[x, t] + 1/2 g h[x, t]^2 + g h[x, t] hb[x];`

Find the energy balance:

`sol = Solve[{consLaw1, consLaw2, 
     Integrate[D[Etotal[h, m], t], x] + a[x, t] == 0}, {a[x, t], 
     D[h[x, t], t], D[m[x, t], t]}][[1]][[1]];`

Answer: 
`a[x, t] -> g (h[x, t] + hb[x]) m[x, t] + m[x, t]^3/(2 h[x, t]^2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@N0va s comment answers the question: `Solve[{D[h[x,t],t]+D[h[x,t],x]==0,Integrate[D[h[x,t],t],x]+a[x,t]==0},{a[x,t],D[h[x,t],t]}]`  gives the expected result.